# Query builder - How to do sql query to generate stamp

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm trying to do a sql query to generate a stamp but i'm having problems when i try to do that in laravel.

The sql query is this and work fine on sql:

`Select '_'+left(newid(),5)+right(newid(),5)+ left(newid(),5)+right(newid(),5)`

And i'm doing this in laravel:

`DB::table('table')->select(DB::raw("'_'+left(newid(),5)+right(newid(),5)+ left(newid(),5)+right(newid(),5)"))->get()->first();`

But i have this error:

`cannot access empty property`

What is the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Just put ->toSql() instead of ->get() and check the query.. paste it here so we can see whats wrong at the query level

Comment: The result: select 'AX'+left(newid(),5)+right(newid(),5)+ left(newid(),5)+right(newid(),5) from [table] . This code works in sql.

Comment: Do you get a file name and line number for that error?

Comment: Are you using MS SQL?

Comment: No. I just have the error "cannot access empty property". @mopo922

Comment: Yes, i'm using MS SQL. @Devon

Comment: @user3242861 Have you tried doing just `DB::select(DB::raw(...))`?   I personally wouldn't recommend this approach for generating an ID.  One of the great things about Laravel is database abstraction.  Here, you're making your app reliant on MSSQL using the `newid()` function.  Why can't you reproduce this output in PHP?

Comment: Yes, i can do that in php, is another option. Do you have any example how to create a stamp like this in php? @Devon

Comment: Well, I'm not going to write it for you, but you could start with something like http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

Comment: Ok, thanks for helping me. @Devon